# How to remove a custom tag and content between in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, tags

Say if I had this tag in a string:
`[phpbay]{keyword}, 30, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "2", "", "", ""[/phpbay]`
Could I remove it and the content between the tags? Maybe using regex? Thanks!

Comment: Which part are you trying to get?

Comment: `str_replace($string, "", $string);`?

Comment: Yes, you could remove it using regular expressions. :)

Comment: I'm trying to get everything in the [phpbay] [/phpbay] tags. The string will also have other content in it, so I wanted to remove just that tag from it. :)

Comment: What's the tag? [phpbay] or {keyword}? Both?

Comment: Just the [phpbay] ones. Everything inside of them tags needs to be removed, along with the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('~\[phpbay\](.+?)\[/phpbay\]~','',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a regex might be feasible here:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\[phpbay][{\w},\s\d"]+\[/phpbay]#', "", $str);
```

This just removes the "tag" from the string if it contains only such characters as in your example. If you only wanted to remove it if it contains e.g. your example `30` or a specific `{keyword}` you would have to make the regex more specific.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for some tools that might help.

Comment: That really does not seem the right idea here. Just looking for certain characters between end points seems wrong, and you also have the wrong right end point.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "[phpbay]blah blah blah [/phpbay]";
$stripped_string = preg_replace('~\[\/?phpbay\]~', '', $string);
```

if I'm reading your question right, and want only the "blah blah blah" part to remain.

Answer (score 1):

This regEx will give you everything between those two tags:

```
\[phpbay](.+)\[/phpbay]
```

Comment: That will remove everything from the first `[phpbay]` through **the last** `[/phpbay]`, not the first or matching one.  I bet that that’s wrong.

Comment: @tchrist: if you use it with `preg_replace`. If you however match the captured group...

Answer (score -1):

I personally would use str_replace or str_ireplace (case Insensitive)

```
$Find = array("[phpbay]","[/phpbay]");
$Replace = array("<b>","</b>");
$Source = "[phpbay]Hello World[/phpbay]";


//Couldn't get any simpler...Replace [phpbay]Content[/phpbay] with <b>Content</b>

echo str_ireplace($Find,$Replace,$Source);
```

Tried and tested, it works.

Hope this helps!